# Why removing CompatibilityVersion results in returning 404 when an exception is thrown in controller (instead of 500)

Tags: asp.net-core

Consider this aspnet core 2.2 code (very boilerplate):

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       app.UseMvc();
    }
}


[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

As it is, calling api/values returns 500. 
Commenting out *services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);* makes it return 404, however.

What's happening in SetCompatibilityVersion that makes it behave this way?

Comment: I could not get 404 error.Could you share more details about your environment?What's the version of your visual studio?Did you host your project?If so,how do you host,In-process or Out-of-process?Where do you host,on IIS or other site?

Answer (score 0):

The default compatibility for ASP.NET Core 2.2 is 2.0, so you probably would need to downgrade your app to 2.0 to make it work without calling `SetCompatibilityVersion`.
For more information see [Compatibility version for ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/compatibility-version?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
.
You can also have a look at which options are affected in the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/MvcOptionsConfigureCompatibilityOptions.cs).